# VB.net: How to select a file to upload and then use FileStream to upload to server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, file-upload, upload

I have an asp form that has the user select a doc file from their pc.  Then when they submit, it uploads to the server.  The problem is how to access that file and read it so I can Upload it.

Front End:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" />
```

Back End:
I have some cloud verification that works and this

```
fs = File.OpenRead("file location.  If I hard code path to file this works")
Dim b(FileUpload.FileBytes.Length) As Byte
Do While fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0
 blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fs)
Loop
fs.Close()
```

The problem is finding a way to read that FileUpload because I can't read the exact location of the file on their pc.  I could use FileUpload.SaveAs() to temporarily save it and then use server.MapPath to upload the file but I'm hoping there's a better way.  Anyone know how to read this file so I can then upload it?

NOTE: I'm using CloudStorage to Save it to a container on azure.  I need the fileupload saves as a filestream.  Also if someone can tell me what the Do While does? because I can also upload without it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is a stream. With that stream you can send the data where you want. Don't forget to check HasFile first.